# How to loop through list and create plotly graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a line graph using plotly but keep getting the below error

```
ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references or list of columns for both `x` and `y`
```

Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

```
area_name = df["StationName"]
area_name = pd.unique(area_name)
for i in area_name:
    print("Data for {} area".format(i))
    df2 = df2[df2.StationName== i]
    df_avg = df2.groupby(df2.month_year, as_index=True)['Price'].mean()
    fig = px.line(df_avg, x = df_avg.index.to_timestamp(), y = df_avg,
    labels=dict(x="Period (Month/Year)", y="Price (£)"), title='Average House Price in {0}'.format(i))
    fig.show()
```

Comment: I have about 50 values in "area_name". The code creates 1 graph and then throws the 
ValueError: Cannot accept list of column references or list of columns for both `x` and `y` error

Comment: for `px.line`, you usually pass a column name or multiple column names to the `y` argument. can you explain why you're passing df_avg as the dataframe as well? also what does the output from the first figure look like?

Comment: @DerekO, as you notice from the code, df_avg does my mean calculation and hence i pass the index (x) and the values (y) into px.line.
The output from the first figure is a line graph of average prices for the first area_name from my "area_name". The figure is correctly produced, but once the next "area_name" is in counter i, it throws the above error.

Comment: can you add a print statement like `print(df_avg)` or `print(df_avg.shape)` before you define `fig` in the loop? and then update your question with the output? that would help us debug a bit more